# How to set up apache basic authentification with shiny server opensource?

Tags: r, apache, centos, basic-authentication, shiny-server

I am trying to setup apache basic authentification to shiny server running on Cent OS 7

For the moment I figured out how to set up the authentification to basic html files floowing this tutorial
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=httpd&f=8

Howerver when trying to change the location directory in the configuration file to /srv/shiny-server nothing works, here is the configuration file I am referring to

```
[root@www ~]# vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/auth_basic.conf
# create new
<Directory /var/www/html/auth-basic>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Basic Authentication"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Does anyone have an ideo on how to make this work for shiny-server?

Thanks